# Opensource alternative to Azure Application Insights?

Tags: visual-studio, logging, exception

Application Insights has a great feature that can open an execption in Visual Studio and then debug with the current state of all the variables and objects.

I have been looking around for a open source alternative that can do the same, but I have not found anything similar. What I want to achive is quite simple. I want to dump all the state of my objects/variables when an exception occours, save it somewhere and then later on be able to load it into Visual Studio.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Also looking for something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights appears to be an Application Performance Monitoring tool.
These generally seem to be language/platform specific, but the best known open source alternative I could find is called [insepctIT](https://github.com/inspectIT/inspectIT), which is for the Java ecosystem.

It appears that you can cobble together multiple tools to get the same job done in other ecosystems, [OpenAPM](https://openapm.io/landscape) seems to have a tool that lets you compare different pieces of the overall APM workflow and put together a monitoring solution for your app.

I realize this doesn't solve the specifics of your question related to debugging in Visual Studio, but it could help others that run across this question on google.